# I got git lfs authorization error

Tags: git

```
git config 'lfs.https://rakibul_dsb@bitbucket.org/doclilyinc/onedoclily.git/info/lfs.locksverify' false
Git LFS: (0 of 50 files) 59.43 MB / 59.43 MB                                   
Authentication required: Authorization error: https://bitbucket.org/%7B%7D/%7Bdec242d9-5890-4905-9c70-4aacf58bc4ac%7D/info/lfs/object/verify?upload_id=a81b7bdf-3d9e-470a-bcb1-0fcc845d45ec
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: yes, i needed to change the origin to use ssh protocol.